# Handling tuples as values within a dictionary (in list comprehensions)

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I have a dictionary like this:

```
>>> pprint.pprint(d)
{'a': ('abc', 'pqr', 'xyz'),
 'b': ('abc', 'lmn', 'uvw'),
 'c': ('efg', 'xxx', 'yyy')}
```

Now, given a variable `x`, I want to be able to list all the keys from the dict where the first element in the tuple is equal to `x`. Hence I do this (on Python 2.6):

```
>>> [ k for k, v in d if v[0] == x ]
```

And I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack
```

How can I correct this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're almost there, just forgot the `.items()` with the dict:

```
>>> d = {'a': ('abc', 'pqr', 'xyz'),
...  'b': ('abc', 'lmn', 'uvw'),
...  'c': ('efg', 'xxx', 'yyy')}
>>> x = 'abc'
>>> [ k for k, v in d.items() if v[0] == x ]
['a', 'b']
```

---

If you don't want to use `.items`, you could iterate on the key itself as well:

```
>>> [ k for k in d if d[k][0] == x ]
['a', 'b']
```

Comment: So that means `for k,v in d` is an invalid statement? Does it always have to be `.items()`?

Comment: @freecode yes. When you do `k, v`, you are implying that the value in this case be unpacked into 2; however, since you don't use `.items` (or `.iteritems` for that matter), you essentially can't unpack the values, which throws the `ValueError`.